# Dynamic type in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic, type-conversion, runtime

Is it possible to determine the data-type to use during runtime? Let's consider an example code like this:

```cpp
void myFunction(type) {

    new std::unordered_map<type, type> umap;
}
...
```

I'm aware that I can make use of `std::any` to support multi-types but I just want to know if there's any way to do the former.

Thanks!

Comment: You can not determine a data type at runtime; all the types are fixed at compile-time. You can use type-erasure techniques to make groups of types all appear the same (base classes are the most well-known, but `std::any` and `std::variant` are other ways to achieve this). The ultimate form of type erasure is `void*`, but you won't get very far with it alone unless you also pass something around next to it so that your application knows what to cast it into.

Comment: You could make `myFunction()` be a template function, where `type` is a template argument deduced by the type of value passed into the function.

Comment: To add to @RemyLebeau answer, look here: [Function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template).

Comment: Types are a compile-time construct.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can by using [templates with C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), for quick example :

```
template<typename genericType>
void myFunction(genericType variable) {
   unordered_map<genericType, genericType> umap;
}
```

ps: i don't think you need to use **new** keyword here.